# How to Stop left Pane from resizing towards left or right? tkinter Panedwindow

Tags: tkinter

How to Stop left Pane from resizing towards left or right? I have already used stretch 'never' but it is not working. Any suggestion will be much appreciated on this. Thanks...

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.title('Flash')
win.geometry('800x600')
m1 = PanedWindow(bd=0.5,sashwidth =15,bg ='black')
m1.pack(fill = BOTH,expand = 1)
left = Label(m1, text ='Left Pane')
m1.add(left,width =150,stretch='never')
m2 = PanedWindow(m1,orient = VERTICAL,bd=0)
m1.add(m2)
right = Label(m1, text ='Right Pane')
m2.add(right)
win.mainloop()
```

[Panedwindow Tkinter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bgHb.png)

Comment: You can simply use two frames instead of `PaneWindow`.

Comment: Are you saying, in panedwindow it is not possible to stop panes from stretching?